# Complex INSERT or UPDATE MariaDB tables with data from other MariaDB tables using JOIN or UNION

Tags: mysql, mariadb

I need to INSERT or UPDATE data in a table using data from other tables; I understand the basic

```
insert into table (a,b,c) 
select h, i, j 
from otherTable 
where........
```

My challenge comes from the fact that the data is spread across multiple tables and in one of the tables the data is metadata stored in rows, not columns. Therefore I need to use JOIN and possible UNION to get what is needed.

Unfortunately after trying everything I read in both the Maria manual, on the Maria forum  and on Stack overflow I can not get it to work.

Here is what I am attempting to do:

insert data into dbc_jot_groupmembers in the following fields using source data as shown:

```
jot_grpid = dbc_bp_groups_members.group_id
jot_bbmemid = dbc_bp_groups_members.user_id  
jot_grpmemname = dbc_bp_xprofile_data.value where field_id=3
jot_grpmemnum = dbc_bp_xprofile_data.value where field_id=4
```

I need the final result to look like this:

```
select * from dbc_jot_groupmembers;

+--------------+-----------+----------------+---------------+---------------------+-------------+
| jot_grpmemid | jot_grpid | jot_grpmemname | jot_grpmemnum | jot_grpmemts        | jot_bbmemid |
+--------------+-----------+----------------+---------------+---------------------+-------------+
|            1 |        17 | hutchdad       | +17047047045  | 2021-06-15 14:56:19 |        14   |
|            2 |        24 | hutchdad       | +17047047045  | 2021-06-15 19:49:58 |        14   |
|            3 |        25 | hutchdad       | +17047047045  | 2021-06-15 19:49:58 |        14   |
|            4 |        17 | hutchmom       | +17773274355  | 2021-06-15 19:49:58 |        15   |
|            5 |        24 | hutchmom       | +17773274355  | 2021-06-15 19:49:58 |        15   |
|            6 |        16 | ledwards       | +14567655645  | 2021-06-15 19:49:58 |        11   |
|            7 |        16 | medwards       | +12223334545  | 2021-06-15 19:49:58 |        10   |
|            7 |        20 | medwards       | +12223334545  | 2021-06-15 19:49:58 |        10   |
```

SAMPLE DATA FROM SOURCE TABELS AND TABLE DEFINITIONS:

```
MariaDB [devDisciplePlaceCom]> describe dbc_bp_groups_members;
+---------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field         | Type         | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+---------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| id            | bigint(20)   | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| group_id      | bigint(20)   | NO   | MUL | NULL    |                |
| user_id       | bigint(20)   | NO   | MUL | NULL    |                |
| inviter_id    | bigint(20)   | NO   | MUL | NULL    |                |
| is_admin      | tinyint(1)   | NO   | MUL | 0       |                |
| is_mod        | tinyint(1)   | NO   | MUL | 0       |                |
| user_title    | varchar(100) | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| date_modified | datetime     | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| comments      | longtext     | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| is_confirmed  | tinyint(1)   | NO   | MUL | 0       |                |
| is_banned     | tinyint(1)   | NO   |     | 0       |                |
| invite_sent   | tinyint(1)   | NO   |     | 0       |                |
+---------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
12 rows in set (0.002 sec)
```

```
 describe dbc_bp_xprofile_data;
+--------------+---------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field        | Type                | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+--------------+---------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| id           | bigint(20) unsigned | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| field_id     | bigint(20) unsigned | NO   | MUL | NULL    |                |
| user_id      | bigint(20) unsigned | NO   | MUL | NULL    |                |
| value        | longtext            | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| last_updated | datetime            | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
+--------------+---------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
5 rows in set (0.001 sec)
```

THIS IS THE LIST OF GROUPS AND WHAT USERS THEY ARE IN.

```
select group_id,user_id  from dbc_bp_groups_members ;

+----------+---------+
| group_id | user_id |
+----------+---------+
|       16 |      13 |
|       16 |      12 |
|       16 |      11 |
|       16 |      10 |
|       17 |      14 |
|       17 |      15 |
|       17 |      16 |
|       17 |      17 |
|       17 |      18 |
|       17 |      19 |
|       20 |      10 |
|       24 |      14 |
|       24 |      16 |
|       24 |      15 |
|       24 |      17 |
|       24 |      19 |
|       25 |      19 |
|       25 |      14 |
|        1 |      14 |
|       11 |      14 |
+----------+---------+
20 rows in set (0.000 sec)
```

THIS IS THE TABLE CONTAINING THE USERS METADATA. IN MY CASE I NEED THE PHOEN NUMBER AND NAME WHICH ARE IN THE value FIELD WITH A field_id of 3 and 4.

```
select * from dbc_bp_xprofile_data where user_id > 9 and field_id > 2 AND field_id < 5;

+-----+----------+---------+---------------+---------------------+
| id  | field_id | user_id | value         | last_updated        |
+-----+----------+---------+---------------+---------------------+
|  31 |        3 |      10 | medwards      | 2021-06-24 03:11:59 |
|  34 |        3 |      11 | ledwards      | 2021-06-24 03:11:24 |
|  37 |        3 |      12 | nedwards      | 2021-04-24 14:47:18 |
|  40 |        3 |      13 | iedwards      | 2021-04-24 14:47:52 |
|  43 |        3 |      14 | hutchdad      | 2021-06-21 14:53:08 |
|  46 |        3 |      15 | hutchmom      | 2021-06-24 03:10:58 |
|  49 |        3 |      16 | hutchdaughter | 2021-04-24 16:54:48 |
|  52 |        3 |      17 | hutchson1     | 2021-04-24 16:55:43 |
|  55 |        3 |      18 | hutchson2     | 2021-04-24 16:57:42 |
|  58 |        3 |      19 | hutchson3     | 2021-04-24 16:58:44 |
|  78 |        3 |      25 | demoadmin     | 2021-06-08 02:01:39 |
| 158 |        4 |      14 | 7047047045    | 2021-06-21 14:53:08 |
| 190 |        3 |      58 | dupdup        | 2021-06-23 19:46:19 |
| 191 |        4 |      15 | 7773274355    | 2021-06-24 03:10:58 |
| 193 |        4 |      11 | 4567655645    | 2021-06-24 03:11:24 |
| 195 |        4 |      10 | 2223334545    | 2021-06-24 03:11:59 |
+-----+----------+---------+---------------+---------------------+
16 rows in set (0.000 sec)
```

If this can not be done is a single INSERT then I can use an INSERT with subsequent UPDATE statements. I also understand that this is not best practice and violates 3nf and probably several other best practice principles. Unfortunately, I am at the mercy of the application and can not change the code, so the only way to get this to work is to put duplicate data in the database as described below:

Comment: Pls share sample data and your attempt so far.

Comment: How do you get `jot_grpmemid` value? What if some `user_id` don't have the numerical value for `jot_grpmemnum`? Should it be set to `0`? If it has numerical value, must it be concatenated with the plus(`+`) symbol?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It can be done with a single `INSERT`. However, there are some information need to be addressed as what I've posted in a the comment. In the meantime, here is an example query that you can use to do the operation that you want:

```
SELECT  ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY A.group_id, A.user_id) AS 'jot_grpmemid',
        A.group_id AS 'jot_grpid', 
        MAX(CASE WHEN B.field_id=3 THEN B.value ELSE '' END) AS 'jot_grpmemname',
        MAX(CASE WHEN B.field_id=4 THEN CONCAT('+',B.value) ELSE '' END) AS 'jot_grpmemnum', 
        A.user_id AS 'jot_bbmemid'
 FROM
dbc_bp_groups_members A JOIN dbc_bp_xprofile_data B
ON A.user_id=B.user_id
GROUP BY A.group_id, A.user_id;
```

Like I said in the comment, I'm not sure how you get/generate `jot_grpmemid` because you have two `7` in the expected result so I assume it's a typo. I guess, at this point it's up to you to modify the query accordingly.

[Demo fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mariadb_10.5&fiddle=391de5115743bba890111fee34185676)

Comment: @Shadow: Some sample data was provided in the initial post (last 2 tables) . Please let me know if there is something more specific you want to see. 

My initial attempts at the proper queries have been laughable at best. I can not even get the initial JOIN correct to obtain the jot_brpmemnumber and jot_grpmemname without duplicates
```
select * FROM dbc_bp_xprofile_data AS f3 JOIN dbc_bp_xprofile_data AS f4 ON f3.field_id=3 AND f4.field_id=4 
```
above gives me incorrect output (associates the number with every user) . I am really at a loss and did not think this would be so difficult.

Comment: This is the purpose of SO, you post a question when you can't find a solution and nothing is laughable when you're trying. Have you tried my suggestion yet? And please open the demo fiddle link to see what the query is doing.

Comment: This is super awesome and I would have never gotten this in the way you did it!  I will have to digest your query a bit and modify as needed ie: as you asked jot_grpmemid will be an auto increment on the insert so I don't need to generate it (the dup 7 was a typo)

I will play with this to remove that jot_grpmemid and hopefully turn this into the insert. 

Thank you again for your help and rapid response!

Comment: I didn't see your response until just now but as mentioned above ... its great and I should be able to get where I need with it.  I have never used demo fiddle before but will check it out. I have done a fair bit of MySQL in my time but  usually building the systems, setting up replication, backups and some light 'flat' queries.  

thanks AGAIN!